# Does Spring's validation routine support Hibernate's JSR 303 implementation option for fail fast mode?

Tags: spring, hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

[8.2. Fail fast mode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-specifics.html#d0e3142)

I'm looking for where I might configure this option in Spring, but I'm not sure this is a part of JSR 303 so much as it is a Hibernate configuration for their own validator implementation. This is important because if I have multiple constraint violations I only want the first one "thrown".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using Spring's `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` to set up your validator, you can specify provider-specific configuration properties within the `validationPropertyMap` attribute.

The property name of Hibernate Validator's fail-fast attribute is "hibernate.validator.fail_fast", so you would set up your validator like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

  <bean name="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationPropertyMap">
      <util:map>
        <entry key="hibernate.validator.fail_fast" value="true"/>
      </util:map>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks Gunnar, I'll give it a try. I really like the Hibernate validator implementation of JSR 303. Great work!

Comment: Can you clarify this: "Assuming you're using Spring's LocalValidatorFactoryBean to set up your validator". I'm using annotations to validate form models, and Spring is picking up Hibernate's validator on the classpath. So I'm not necessarily "configuring" it using XML. Will this cause any issues?

Comment: How are you retrieving `Validator` instances in your code? Are you using the Bean Validation bootstrap API (e.g. `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()`) or are you retrieving validators via dependency injection? In that case you have to provide a validator (factory) as Spring bean using `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` (see also Spring reference guide, [section 6.7.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-overview)).

Comment: That was it. So I was following section 6.7.4.3 and allowing Spring to automatically enable validation across controllers. However, I need to follow 6.7.4.2 (second part) and provide a bean validation reference, which would be to the one you gave in your answer. Now fail fast validation works! Thanks!