# Validate all fields at once using hibernate validator

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.0 to build a restful service with the java bean validation framework. Hibernate-Validator is used behind the scenes. The validation works well but throws an exception after one field fails to match the constraint. I would like to validate all fields first and then give the consumer a response with all errors. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use `@Valid` annotation on your request, there is a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` that you could use in an `@ExceptionHandler` method in order to achieve that.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public List<String> handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    //get All errors with
    ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors();
    //and map them
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I misinterpreted the error. The reason why I only saw one error was because it came from Jackson, which rejected the json instead of the hibernate validator.

Answer (score 0):

You probably enabled [fail fast mode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.1#section-fail-fast). Just disable it.

See also [Does Spring's validation routine support Hibernate's JSR 303 implementation option for fail fast mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867020/does-springs-validation-routine-support-hibernates-jsr-303-implementation-opti)

Comment: Thank you. You're also right. Actually I misinterpreted the error. The reason why I only saw one error was because it came from Jackson, which rejected the json instead of the hibernate validator.